# How to use dateModified microdata

Tags: schema

I have written a schema tag that is showing a warning "The property dateModified is not recognized by Google for an object of type Date" in Google Structured Data Testing tool. Below is my code:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Date">
<meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2018-06-07">
```

How will I fix this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This dateModified property can only be used with http://schema.org/CreativeWork or http://schema.org/DataFeedItem.

The problem with your code is that you're telling Google that the type of this item you're marking up is of the type Date, and then giving it a property (dateModified) it does not support.

To fix this, you'd have to do:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
    <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2018-06-07">
</div>
```

Notice I only changed Date to CreativeWork.